# Is liquorice low FODMAP?

Tags: nutrition, diet, digestion, fodmap, fructose

Is pure liquorice juice extracted from the root, solidified, with nothing added, usually sold in sticks or small pieces, non chewable, a low FODMAP ingredient ?

Comment: I think, liquorice contains fructose and possibly some oligosaccharides, which are FODMAPs, so it is probably not low-FODMAP. I do not have any credible link, but search for liquorice (licorice) + fructose, etc. In some low-FODMAP charts it is listed as "to try" or "to avoid."